# Login Integration using reverse proxy through WAM

Tags: aem

I am trying to integrate WAM with AEM application using reverse proxy. I want to know if there is any way of differentiating pages for unauthenticated and authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

There's a concept of **Closed User Group** (CUG) in AEM, where you can implement authentication in few pages of website for few users alone.
You can **add the users who have to login to AEM for few pages in CUG group**, configure the CUG for the pages in page properties. If you have a dispatcher, you have to make some changes in dispatcher for this implementation.

Here is the link [Creating Closed User Group](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-4/sites/administering/using/cug.html) explaining in detail.

Answer (score 0):

AEM ships with a authentication handler called "Adobe Granite SSO Authentication Handler". This let's you map the authentication information sent by WAM proxy to an AEM [JCR] user. IMHO this is the way to go when using a WAM like site minder.

The way this works is you let Sling manage the access control and only depend on WAM to identify the user. So sling decides if the incoming request [anonymous/logged in] has permission to access a page/resource on the repository. If the user doesn't have access, you route the user to WAM's login page rather than AEM's login page.

The above approach works well only when your dealing with adding WAM based authentication for author server. If your intent is to use this on a publish server for large user base then you'd run into issues scaling this.